# geth account creation Failed to enumerate USB devices

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to create a private Ethereum network on a Kubernetes cluster using [ethereum/client-go](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go) docker image but getting bellow error while trying to create an account:

```
~/.ethereum # geth account import privateKey --password passwordfile
INFO [07-10|00:31:02.095] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
WARN [07-10|00:31:02.095] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=4096 updated=1316
INFO [07-10|00:31:02.101] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [07-10|00:31:02.101] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.102] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.106] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.107] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.107] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.107] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:02.107] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:03.109] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:03.109] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-10|00:31:03.109] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
Killed
~/.ethereum # command terminated with exit code 137
```

Things work perfect when I try on a docker container, problem with both Minikube as well as IBM Kubernetes Service.

Comment: has this been resolved?

Comment: can you share you kubenetes config?

Comment: I tried something similar to `stable/ethereum` helm chart’s account creation `initContainer` on Minikube and IBM Kubernetes Service.

Answer (score 7):

Consider using `--nousb` as argument on `geth`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to create Ethereum account in Kubernetes by using `geth` version 1.7.0. Later versions of `geth` check for USB devices (possibly for hardware wallets). My assumption is that Docker containers in Kubernetes do not have USB IO and that's why `geth` throws error when it can't find USB driver. I did try `--nousb` flag, but still it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

you are using one hyphen? here the argument or the option wants two hyphens `--nousb`,

```
geth -h | grep nousb

geth --help | grep nousb
```

only a short-option wants one hyphen.. `-h`  ;)